# Python XML: how to treat a node content as a string?

Tags: python, xml

I have the following code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse(file)
my_val = tree.find('./abc').text
```

and here is an xml snippet:

```
<item>
  <abc>
    <a>hello</a>
    <b>world</b>
    awesome
  </abc>
</item>
```

I need `my_val` of type `string` to contain

```
<a>hello</a>
<b>world</b>
awesome
```

But it obviously resolves to `None`

Comment: Take a look at Beautiful Soup, it will suit you perfectly. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to start by getting the root element

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import string

tree=ElementTree.parse(file)
rootElem=tree.getroot()
```

Then we can get element abc from root and iterate over its children, formatting into a string using attributes of the children:

```
abcElem=root.find("abc")
my_list = ["<{0.tag}>{0.text}</{0.tag}>".format(child) for child in abcElem]
my_list.append(abcElem.text)
my_val = string.join(my_list,"\n")
```

I'm sure some other helpful soul knows a way to print these elements out using ElementTree or some other xml utility rather than formatting them yourself but this should start you off.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration over`findall` will give you a list of subtrees elements.

```
>>> elements = [ElementTree.tostring(x) for x in tree.findall('./abc/')]
    ['<a>hello</a>\n    ', '<b>world</b>\n    awesome\n  ']
```

The problem with this is that text without is tags are appended to the previous tag. So you need to clean that too:

```
>>> split_elements = [x.split() for x in elements]
    [['<a>hello</a>'], ['<b>world</b>', 'awesome']]
```

Now we have a list of lists that needs to be flatten:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> flatten_list = list(chain(*split_elements))
    ['<a>hello</a>', '<b>world</b>', 'awesome']
```

Finally, you can print it one per line with:

```
>>> print("\n".join(flatten_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

This might be not the best solution but it worked for me

```
my_val = ElementTree.tostring(tree.find('./abc'), 'utf-8', 'xml').decode('utf-8')
my_val = my_val.replace('<abc>', '').replace('</abc>', '')
my_val = my_val.strip()
```

Comment: This will fail if you have more <abc> inside the main <abc>.